# Need help converting JPG link to GIF format

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm trying to get an image from a website to display on a Label widget but Tkinter only accepts GIF and BMP format. Pretty much all images I find are JPG or PNG.
The code I have now is as follows:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

url = "http://www.wired.com/wp-  
content/uploads/2015/03/10182025tonedfull- 
660x441.jpg"
u = urlopen(url)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()
import base64
b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I get an error message saying that it cannot recognize the image. If anyone has any idea how I can fix it please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: In tcl/tk 8.6+, PhotoImage also works with .png files, but PIL or pillow are still needed for anything else. 8.6 comes with 3.4, 3.5 PSF Windows installer, some Linux systems, and some alternate Mac installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should let you load JPG files:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from cStringIO import StringIO
from urllib import urlopen
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
url = "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/10182025tonedfull-660x441.jpg"
u = urlopen(url)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

image_file = Image.open(StringIO(raw_data))
photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_file)
label = tk.Label(image=photo_image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You do not need to base64 encode it, but you do need to use `ImageTk` to load the image. This would display as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Jpg with image, you have to also import ImageTk

A very basic working example could be:

```
  import io
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import Tkinter as tk
    from urllib2 import urlopen

    root = tk.Tk()
    url = "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/10182025tonedfull-660x441.jpg"
    image_bytes = urlopen(url).read()
    data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_image, bg='brown')
    label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```